# unable to locate package cgroups-lite

Tags: package-management, command-line

```
$ sudo apt-get install cgroups-lite
[sudo] password for neethu: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cgroups-lite
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `cgroups-lite`.it's `cgroup-lite`.So try to install `cgroup-lite` by running the below command,

```
sudo apt-get install cgroup-lite
```

#### How did i know?

If you face any `E: Unable to locate package` error while installing a package,then there may be a chance of mispelt the package name.you have to search for the packages availabe on that name by cutting down the last letters,

```
apt-cache search package-name
```

In your case i had cutdown `-lite` from the package name you mentiond.

```
$ apt-cache search cgroups

cgroup-lite - Light-weight package to set up cgroups at system boot
libpam-systemd - system and service manager - PAM module
ulatency - scriptable latency regulator using cgroups (client)
ulatencyd - scriptable latency regulator using cgroups (server)
```

So the correct package is `cgroup-lite`.